# GKE use ValidatingAdmissionWebhooks instead of PodNodeSelector admission plugin

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I would like to deploy a namespaced pod in a labeled node. This is possible using annotations on namespaces and podNodeSelector admission controller. (adding this annotations on the namespace:
"scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-selector: key=value", pods are automatically scheduled on the nodes labeled with key=value) How can achieve this in GKE? I think the only way is to create a validatingadmissionwebhooks, can you help me implement the logic and point me to some example or documentation?

Tnx in advance, Pierluigi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GKE. you can explicitly deploy a Pod to a specific node pool by setting a nodeSelector in the Pod manifest. This forces a Pod to run only on nodes in that node pool. For an example see, Deploy a Pod to a specific node pool.

You can see this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-pools#deploy) which outline how to Deploy a Pod to a specific node pool.

Here is some [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) on how to send a mutated webhook and how to configure them. Here are some examples [3](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/additional_concepts/dynamic_admission_controllers.html#types-of-admission-webhooks) and [4](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers.md) also that are helpful.

Comment: Sure, but I am asking something different. I am asking how I can automatically add nodeselector through mutating webhook since nodeSelector admission plugin afaik is not enabled in GKE.

Comment: I know what nodeselector is, I want the manifest to be patched automatically.<br>
- this is possible in kubernetes with nodeselector admission plugin
- afaik in gke is not possible to install admission controller plugin
- in gke you need to use webhooks
- the example I am looking for is the code (go or python) the webhooks need to call through an http api call.